# How to get an group data from sql?

Tags: sql, wordpress

Can anyone help me create chart like the one below? I'm using CFDB on wordpres. It is a simple form inputs counter.

I've figured out something like this:

```
SELECT month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submit_time`)) as miesiac,
       year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submit_time`)) as rok,
       `form_name`, `field_name`, `field_value`, `field_order`, `file`
FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`
WHERE year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submit_time`)) = 2016
```

I would like to get final result like in the attachment.

[image]

Now I get something like this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZyqq.jpg)

Comment: add more details. plus tabel current result and expected result

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the data needed for a chart like the one in your example, you need to return the number of form submissions for each month and form type.

```
SELECT COUNT(sub.form_name) as total, sub.form_name, sub.miesiac  
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `submit_time`, month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submit_time`)) as miesiac, 
      `form_name`
    FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`
    WHERE year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submit_time`)) = 2016 ) sub
GROUP BY sub.form_name, sub.miesiac
```

The sub-query identifies the distinct submissions (since each submission has multiple rows) and the main query counts the number of submissions for each form type per month. There's no need to include the year because it's already included in the WHERE statement.

Comment: I got something like this right now : "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string ×"

Comment: Can you provide a few more details?  Are you visualizing the data with another plugin?